# Derivation of the expectation of an exponential

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, exponential-distribution

I would like to demonstrate the formula which states that if

$X$ is a random variable such that

$\forall \lambda >0, E[e^{-\lambda^2.\frac{X}{2}}] = e^{-\lambda.b}$

Where $b$ is a positive constant.

Then by derivation regardng $\lambda^2$ and taking $\lambda = 0$.

Once can calculate $E[X]$

In order to demonstrate this statement, I thought of using whole series to demonstrate such a purpose. However this lead me nowhere...

Can you please advise?!!

Thank you

Comment: This random variable does not have finite mean. You can show that $EX =\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypothesis can be written as $Ee^{-tX}=e^{-\sqrt {2t} b}$ for all $t>0$. Differentiating  w.r.t. $t$ (from the right) and setting $t=0$ we get $EX=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks fr your answer! When you differentiate w.r.t t, can you say that $\frac{\partial E[e^{-tX}]}{\partial t} = E[-X.e^{-tX}]$?

Comment: @Xman Prove by contradiction. Suppose $X$ has finite mean. Then you can justify the fact that $-EX=(Ee^{-tX})'(0)$. But RHS works out to $-\infty $ from the formula for $Ee^{-tX}$.

Comment: thank you it's clear now!